# Chromium up to date

Tags: chromium

I have recently installed chromiunm via

> sudo apt-get install chromium-browser

How can I ensure of running the most up-to-date chromium? And if I'm not running the most up to date, how can I update my chromium. I'm running lts 14.04. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Rerun that same command to get the latest version/updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to retrieve the latest list of packages available run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Next, to apply most of all the system updates without making any other changes to the system, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If there is a newer version available, it will be installed.

Finally, you can run a dist-upgrade instead of upgrade and this will fully apply all updates but you may have to reinstall any drivers you compiled from source such as the nvidia driver if manually installed. If you are not using anything funny like that I recommend you do a dist-upgrade instead as there are often many security updates applied to the linux kernel that will not be applied if you only run a simple upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If there are any kernel updates installed, you will need to reboot after installation.